# Cubic spline-interpolations with extra conditions of $f(x)=x^4$

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, interpolation, spline, numerical-calculus

Let $f(x)=x^4$ and $x\in[-1,1]$. How can I find a cubic Spline $S$ that is an interpolation polynomial at the data points $x_0=-1, x_1=0$ and $x_2=1$? $S$ should also fulfill the extra condition $S'(-1)=f'(-1)$ and $S'(1)=f'(1)$.

Right now I'm learning numerical calculus and currently I'm trying to wrap my head around how spline-interpolation works. How would I go about this question for example? I thought of defining two spline-functions $S_1(x):=a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0$ and $S_2(x):=b_3x^3+b_2x^2+b_1x+b_0$, where $S(x)|_{x\in[-1,0]}=S_1(x)$ and $S(x)|_{x\in[0,1]}=S_2(x)$. This would lead me to six equations, since $S_1(-1)=1,S_0(0)=0,S_2(0)=0,S_2(1)=1,S'_1(-1)=-4$ and $S'(1)=4$. But since I have 8 variables, this problem isn't solvable (yet). What am I missing/doing wrong? (I also tried adding the two conditions $S'_1(0)=S'_2(0)$ and $S''_1(0)=S_2''(0)$ in order to get an $S\in \mathcal{C}^2$ and 8 equations, although even that seems to not help.

Comment: Can you elaborate why that last point didn't help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is completely valid. If you set  up these equations you'lle nd up  with a system that looks like so:
$$
\begin{array}[c]
SS_1(x_0) = f(x_0) \\
S_1(x_1) = f(x_1) \\
S_2(x_1) = f(x_1) \\
S_2(x_2) = f(x_2) \\
S_1'(x_0) = f'(x_0) \\
S_2'(x_2) = f'(x_2) \\
S_1'(x_1) = S_2'(x_1) \\
S_1''(x_1) = S_2''(x_1) \\
\end{array}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_0^3 & x_0^2 & x_0 & 1 & & & & \\
x_1^3 & x_1^2 & x_1 & 1 & & & & \\
& & & & x_1^3 & x_1^2 & x_1 & 1\\
& & & & x_2^3 & x_2^2 & x_2 & 1\\
3x_0^2 & 2x_0 & 1 & & & & & \\
 & &  & & 3x_2^2 & 2x_2 & 1 & \\
3x_1^2 & 2x_1 & 1  & & -3x_1^2 & -2x_1 & -1\\
6x_1 & 2 & & & -6x_1^2 & -2 & & \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}a_3 \\ a_2 \\ a_1 \\ a_0 \\ b_3 \\ b_2 \\ b_1 \\ b_0 \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 
f(x_0) \\
f(x_1) \\
f(x_1) \\
f(x_2) \\
f'(x_0) \\
f'(x_2) \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The determinant of the matrix is [12](https://tio.run/##RY2xDoMwDET3foXHRLoMSYBEoH4JYoggQycqQAz9@dQYWiRLvnu2z/O4pT2XkuhJn7zMq4qgqLtHUha2rTTz3lgQl7ThGDnIwB7aI/51hbq9Xc0BXgI8jMN52vBKuOCPBfQOFAbB8khwFNycmJVxjKfX@lZJX2LKGxvdlfIF) and it is therefore invertible.

Comment: Thank you! I came to the same matrix, calculated it by hand and got very weird numbers, like $a_3=-\frac{13}{4}$ two times in a row. That didn't make any sense to me since my calculations looked valid and I thought it had to be the wrong way to solve this. Turns out by checking your system of equations again and plugging in the values for $x_i, f(x_i)$ and $f'(x_i)$ it's actually working out now: $S_1(x)=-2x^3-x^2$ and $S_2(x)=2x^3-x^2$ are working out perfectly.